# Add a timeline, horizontal bar on Qt

Tags: c++, qt, timeline

I'm trying to make a sampler module on Qt, I've already made a lot of buttons with QtDesigner, it looks like that:

[image]

I would like to create a horizontal bar which is moves from left to right over all the buttons, this bar is a timebar. So it would be like a QProgressBar but I need a thin bar which doesn't prevent from clicking all the buttons. Do you guys have an idea ?

Thanks,
Robin

Answer (score 0):

It is very custom thing, so no predefined solutions will works.

There are many ways to do that. I will describe you the easiest one.

You can place QProgressBar as you wanted on the top of your buttons (did I get you right?) and after that you can do like that (code is not for copy-paste, just read it as pseudo-code):

```
progressBar->installEventFilter(this);

// Then you create method for event filtering in your MainWindow or who handles that ProgressBar

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) {
  if (static_cast<QProgressBar *>(obj) == progressBar) {
    // Then check if event is mouse click event
    // and now iterate over your buttons. If some button->rect().contains() event->pos() that was clicked, call button->clicked() signal.
  }
}
```